# Apply boolean mask at position to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mask

I've been looking around for a while now and can't find the answer to my specific problem.

Let's say I have this empty 2D numpy array of dtype Object and a boolean mask:

```
class Object(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "aObj"

a = np.empty((7, 10), dtype=Object)
mask = np.array([[False, True, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, True]])
```

I want to apply this mask to assign the records to an instance of Object given the top left position where this mask has to be applied:

```
top_left = (2, 3)
obj = Object()
result = apply_mask(a, mask, top_left, obj)
result

array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, None, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=Object)
```

As you can see row index 2 has the fourth column set to aObject since the first mask row is `[False, True False]`, only the second index should be set to `obj`. Similarly row index 3 has columns 3 and 5 set to `obj` following the second row of the mask: `[True, False, True]`.

I've been looking at the `numpy.ma` modules but I can't find what I'm been looking for. So far I've been messing around with `np.indeces`:

```
yd, xd = np.indices(a.shape)
result = a
result[(xd >= top_left[1]) &
       (xd < top_left[1] + mask.shape[1]) &
       (yd >= top_left[0]) &
       (yd < top_left[0] + mask.shape[0])] = obj
```

But obviously this only results in a rectangle of `obj`, I haven't really applied the mask yet, just the shape.

Any advice?

---

Edit: One important detail is that if another instance of Object was already present in one of the records covered by a False in the mask then that instance should persist. See the following example:

```
a = np.empty((7, 10), dtype=Object)
a[2 ,3] = Object()
mask = np.array([[False, True, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, True]])
top_left = (2, 3)
result = apply_mask(a, mask, top_left, Object())
result

array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, None, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=Object)
```

This does lead me to believe I need the np.ma module since those masked arrays actually support *empty* records.

---

Edit:

Using slicing I can assign an object array at the exact location I want

```
result[top_left[1]:top_left[1] + mask.shape[1],
       top_left[0]:top_left[0] + mask.shape[0]] = obj_array
```

However this doesn't satisfy the constraint mentioned in the previous edit.

So I'm looking at the masked arrays and I would've expected that with the following code it would work, but alas:

```
obj_mask = np.ma.masked_where(~mask, np.full(mask.shape, obj))
result = a
result[top_left[1]:top_left[1] + mask.shape[1],
       top_left[0]:top_left[0] + mask.shape[0]] = obj_mask
result

array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=object)
```

The off-by-one error aside, why is the masked data suddenly available when assigning it to the array?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! In the edits I was already very close.

The off-by-one error was caused by the fact that the indices were swapped and I have to apply the object mask using the np.ma.compressed method.

In full:

```
class Object(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "aObj"

a = np.empty((7, 10), dtype=Object)
a[2, 3] = Object()
mask = np.array([[False, True, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, True]])
top_left = (2, 3)
obj = Object()
a

array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=object)
```

I've added the one Object to show that it persists after applying the mask.

```
obj_mask = np.ma.masked_where(~mask, np.full(mask.shape, obj))
obj_mask

masked_array(
  data=[[--, aObj, --],
        [aObj, --, aObj],
        [aObj, aObj, aObj]],
  mask=[[ True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value='?',
  dtype=object)
```

The mask is created the same way as in the edit.

```
result = a
result[top_left[0]:top_left[0] + mask.shape[0],
       top_left[1]:top_left[1] + mask.shape[1]][~obj_mask.mask] = np.ma.compressed(obj_mask)
result

array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, None, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, aObj, aObj, aObj, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=object)
```

And as you can see, all values are applied.

Lastly:

```
>>> a[2, 3] == a[2, 4]
False

>>> a[2, 4] == a[3, 3]
True
```

As expected.